# Scan Novell NetWare backend with Windows servers and clients

Tags: network, penetration-test, tools, vulnerability-scanners, network-scanners

Could anyone provide some insight on performing an internal vulnerability assessment regarding Novell NetWare as the backend with client workstations and servers running various versions of Windows?

Essentially, I'm looking for tools or techniques on how to run a thorough scan by joining my machine to the Novell "tree" and then launching a scan against the Windows workstations and servers. Additionally, it would be beneficial if a tool exists that scans for vulnerabilities on both systems.

Other questions surrounding this are:

- If there is a separate Windows domain, would I have to join that domain in order to run a scan?
- If the Windows machines are part of a WORKGROUP, would I just need to join the Novell "tree" and enter the Windows admin credentials inside of a scanner tool to scan the Windows machines?
- Could I join the WORKGROUP and run the scan with the Novell NetWare admin credentials used inside of the scanner tool?

To sum up, a person plugs their laptop into an environment running Novell NetWare and wants to scan the Windows clients connected to the Novell server. Please ask for more detail if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you want to do an unauthenticated (black box) style scan or internal audit type scan.  Some scanning tools can check to see if you are missing any patches, in that case you will need to have local credentials for the windows systems.  You will need to use an account that is present on each Windows system with proper rights.

So yes, you could use the workgroup credential to scan the workstations and you don't necessarily need to join the Netware tree.

Comment: It would be an audit type scan where the credentials are known. For example, I've used tools such as GFI LANguard, Nessus, Nexpose, etc., but have ran into access denied issues in the past. I'm trying to be as prepared as possible for future engagements.

Answer (score 1):

You may already have come across this, but depending on the version of NDS in use [pandora](http://www.nmrc.org/project/pandora/index.html)
 may be of interest.